# Change markerfacecolor for some of the markers in Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have a plot that shows markers in a circle. I want to be able to change the colour of 3 of them. I've tried using a variable for markerfacecolor as follows but that doesn't work:

```
    angle = 0.0
    colorR = 'red'
    angleUpdate = 2 * numpy.pi / (len(v.T))
    for i in range(len(v.T)):
        x = numpy.sin(angle)
        y = numpy.cos(angle)
        angle += angleUpdate
        if i < 3:
            colorR = 'green'
        v[0, i] = x
        v[1, i] = y
    plt.plot(v[0], v[1], 'ko', markerfacecolor = colorR, markersize = 70, clip_on = False)
    plt.show()
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

In your plot `'ko'` means put a **black** circle marker; `k` stands for black. You should try:

```
plt.plot(v[0], v[1], 'o', markerfacecolor = 'red')
```

To get the abbreviation of other symbols and colors try:

```
help(plt.plot)
```

You can either achieve your case using `plot` or `scatter`, depending on what you are doing:

```
import pylab as plt
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
plt.plot(x[:5],x[:5],'o',c='r',markersize=10)
plt.plot(x[5:],x[5:],'o',c='b',markersize=10)
plt.show()
```

will generate,
[image]

Similarly, you can also use

```
plt.scatter(x[:5],x[:5],c='r',s=100)
plt.scatter(x[5:],x[5:],c='b',s=100)
```

Comment: the marker is overridden by a large red or green cirlce depending on my if condition. However, I want some of the markers to be red and some to be green in the same plot. Do you know if that is possible? I think maybe I'll put the values in an array and see if plot can iterate through those.

Comment: Thanks - seems pretty straight forward. So I just plot some with a red marker and some with a green. Will let you know how it goes.